# CiFilter not giving proper effects with defaults values.

Tags: ios, colors, effects, core-image, cifilter

Please can any one explain me, How can we identify right values for different  inputs parameter in filters. I tried defaults value but only few filters are giving proper effects for others its not working.

Can anybody guide me to right way to implement CIFilter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The builtin Core Image filters and their default parameter values are documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html

You can set the input parameters of a filter to the default values by calling

```
[filter setDefaults];
```

Comment: I did same [filter setDefaults] but its not giving proper effects for all filters. its working for only fews filters.

Comment: @UserDev What are these "few filters"?

Comment: CIColorCubeWithColorSpace is not giving proper filter effect. Is there any other way to implement this filter.